# determine if excel cell contains formula (VSTO: C# or VB)

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I've got a table:

[image]

The application is required to recognize formulas and to handle them in a special way (for example not overriding them).
Each row is read like this:

```
object[,] formulas = (object[,])worksheet.Range["A2:C2"].Formula;

if (((string)formulas[1,3]).StartsWith("="))
{
    //handle formula
}
```

This solution has an important bug. It seems not able to 'see' the single quote sign, that is:

- `"=A1"`  is read by Formula property as `"=A1"` and recognition works
- `"'=A1"` is read by Formula property as `"=A1"` so it's recognized as formula even if it's not

There is another solution that I've explored, the explicit HasFormula Range property.

```
if ((bool)worksheet.Range["C5"].HasFormula == true)
{
    //handle formula
}
```

HasFormula does not return array so you have to test every cell. This has a huge performance drawback and is the main reason why I read entire rows and not single cells.

So the first solution is unreliable, the second is inefficient and now I'm out of options.
Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Maybe [`SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.specialcells?view=vsto-2017) and `xlCellTypeFormulas`?

Comment: Ok I'm checking this. SpecialCells can generate a non rectangular range that only contains cells whose content are formulas and this is done in a single COM call. Then I have to check if each of my cell is included in the SpecialCells returned range. This has to be done without using excel functions like Intersect because that would be a COM call for each cell and that way we would be back to a big performance problem. I think this solution is not very straightforward yet feasible, I'm trying to implement something like that now. Hoping there are better solution though.

Answer (score 1):

The leading single quote is legacy shorthand for forcing a cell into text mode.

You can access it as a property of an individual cell in VBA/C++ with .PrefixCharacter  method, which returns a single character string or a null if the prefix exists.

```
HasPrefixString = Range("B2").PrefixCharacter
```

C# should have a similar method ( or better)  than VBA or similar to C++.

Comment: That's interesting, unfortunately it can't be done for ranges but only cell-by-cell, that is a COM call for each cell and a great inefficiency. A table of say 10*1000 cells may be read in fractions of a second as a whole, while reading cell by cell may take up to 15 seconds.